# openpyxl cell color reading for html

Tags: html, python-3.x, colors, openpyxl, rgb

I am using openpyxl to read xlsx file and render it's content to html. But sometimes cell color ( I already tried bgcolor and start_color) returning just integer. Here is my code:

```
text = "<tr>"
for j in range(0,last_col_index):
    colorvalue = str(row[j].fill.start_color.value)[2:] #ARGB to RGB
    color = '#' + colorvalue if colorvalue != '000000' else '#FFFFFF' 
    text += ('<td bgcolor="{}" >{}</td>').format(color,str(row[j].value))
text+="</tr>"
```

Here I am omitting two leading characters because openpyxl's color format is ARGB. For #a9d18e color row[j].fill.bgColor.value is returning 64, so HTML  background turning into black. How can I convert openpyxl cell color to simple HTML color properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the colour is an index colour: the format allows colours to specificied using aRGB, tint and index. You can find out which with `type` attribute. We used to keep a list of the aRGB values for the index as defined in the OOXML standard but the definition is incorrect and, in any case, can vary between clients.